# How to make text bold,italic and underline using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have three checkboxes and a textbox now If I write something in textbox and check the bold checkbox the text should appear with bold effect and similarly italic and underline without postback(i.e it should reflect immediately with the selected effect).

Here is my code:

```
Bold:<input type="checkbox" value=""/>
Italic:<input type="checkbox" value=""/>
Underline:<input type="checkbox" value=""/>

<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: i dont think you can style input text like underline, if so you could replace the text input with a element such as a div

Comment: Actually I have tried using this way http://www.script-tutorials.com/text-animation-jquery-ui-slider/ and I need the same to be used for text decoration.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<form>
    Bold:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="bold"/>
    Italic:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="italic"/>
    Underline:<input name="textStyle" type="checkbox" value="underline"/>

    <input name="styledText" type="text" value="">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name="textStyle"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'bold'){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-weight', 'bold');
            else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-weight', 'normal');
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'italic'){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-style', 'italic');
            else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('font-style', 'normal');
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'underline'){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('input[name="styledText"]').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
            else $('input[name="styledText"]').css('text-decoration', 'none');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tyfsf/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for sorting me out this issue.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that using simple CSS and a little jQuery code.

1.First define your cascading style sheet classes

```
<style type="text/css">
.bold {
 font-weight:bold;
}
.italic {
font-style:italic;
}
.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```

2.Load jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

3.Write the function for switching the classes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selector').click(function () {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        if(checked) {
            $('#box').addClass(value);
        } else {
            $('#box').removeClass(value);
        }
    });     

});
</script>
```

5.Modified html

```
Bold:<input class='selector' type="checkbox" value="bold"/>
Italic:<input class='selector' type="checkbox" value="italic"/>
Underline:<input class='selector' type="checkbox" value="underline"/>
<br>
<input id="box" type="text" value="">
<br>
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/t2wKP/

Answer (score 0):

Text inside of an input cannot be formatted this way. You can try and fake it with an [editable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) div.

```
<div contenteditable></div>
```

And use jQuery on that.

Comment: Actually I have tried using this way http://www.script-tutorials.com/text-animation-jquery-ui-slider/ and I need the same to be used for text decoration.