# Here "winningPlayer" contains a text, I want to make it appear bold when it appears upon certain condition. Is it possible to do so?

Tags: jquery

```
$('h1').html(winningPlayer+" has won! Refresh your browser to play again!");
```

I have already tried `.bold()` function but it does not work and since its a variable, I cannot just add the `<strong>` tag around the variable.

Comment: `$('h1').html(winningPlayer+"...").css('font-weight', 'bold')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make text bold,italic and underline using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946196/how-to-make-text-bold-italic-and-underline-using-jquery)

Comment: But .. since a <h1> is already bold, this will look like it does nothing.  So maybe `.bold()` worked and you don't see it.

Comment: His problem is that he wants to add the bold only to the variable, not the whole text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a html() function, you can try by adding the strong tag to the code:

```
$('h1').html("<strong>" + winningPlayer + "</strong> has won! Refresh your browser to play again!");
```

Comment: The `<strong>` tag is used to indicate that a portion of text is important, not to apply bold styling to text.  Most implementations do this by making the text bold.  There is a semantic difference here.  If the intention is to make text appear bold, the `font-weight` style should be used (or perhaps `<b>`)